# Why do questions asked a long time ago, even those whose answers are already accepted, get shown again?

Tags: discussion, support, bumping

For example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769256/10513):

[image]

Comment: As well as providing an image, it is helpful to [link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769256/10513) (so folk can easily investigate).

Comment: @user1729 I will take care of it from now:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may notice that the text "Active: today" in your screenshot actually contains a hyperlink - if you [click on it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1?lastactivity) it goes to [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1/4082549#4082549) that was edited. (In other cases it might go to the question - depending on what caused the bumping.) Also if you see the question in some list of the question which is sorted by recent activity, you can see there "modified 9 hours ago" - if you click on this text, you get the same link. (For other question you can see "answered n hours ago" or "asked n hours ago" - depending on what was the most recent type of activity.)

Then when you view the answer, you can see how it was changed (how it caused bumping) by looking [at the timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info). You can also see the text "edited 9 hours ago" - if you click on this text, you can see [the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4082549/revisions).

I will add that in some cases the reason for bumping question might be tied to an answer that is now deleted. In such cases, the reason for bumping might be hidden from [users who cannot see deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

See also:

- [What is the active link for on the right side of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146959)
- [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)
- [Add link to most recent activity of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4391) and [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#99024) in February 2010
- The [tag-info for last-activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/last-activity/info) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ah , I didn't knew about it

Comment: Another reason for bumping is that questions with 0-score answers are bumped by the Community user (here the bump reason is less obvious).

Answer (score 8):

The reason the 5 year old question shows up again is because it has recent activity. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769256/trying-to-show-that-lnx-lim-n-to-infty-nx1-n-1/4082549#4082549) was edited 15 minutes before you asked this question on meta.

On the [Questions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) you can change the sorting order to newest questions. On the frontpage you can choose between "interesting" and "hot" questions, where this one may still show up because of its 10 upvotes.